# Image as a link for an epub footnote

Tags: epub

The footnote with a text as a link ("1" for example)

```
<a epub:type="noteref" href="#n1">1</a></p>
```

with

```
 <aside id="n1" epub:type="footnote" >
    <p>Hidden content of the aside element.</p>
 </aside>
```

works both on ibooks on the Mac as ibooks on Ipad.

Now, when I change the text ("1") with an image

```
<a epub:type="noteref" href="#n1"><img src="images/testImage.jpg" alt=""/></a></p>
```

The link opens the footnote on iBooks on the Mac but on Ipad and Iphone, iBooks crashes. (My epub file appears without errors from a check with epubchecke-4.0.1).

Why this behavior on Ipad and Iphone? How fix this issue?
Thank you for all hints.a